# get value from loaded page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have main.aspx and second.aspx.The code in main.aspx:

```
<form id="form1">
    <div id="main">
    </div>
</form>
```

And in second.aspx:

```
<div id="second">
    <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="txt1"></asp:Textbox>
    <input type="button" id="bttn" value="send"></input>
</div>
```

At the run time I'm loading second.aspx page into main.aspx div id="main".

```
$("#main").load("second.aspx #second");
```

I'm trying to get the textbox value from main.aspx.But when I tried

```
$("#bttn").click(function(){
    var t=$("txt1").val();
    alert(t);
});
```

It gives nothing.It seems to be never going into the function.How can get the value from the textbox.

Comment: FYI, your selector is wrong too: `$("#txt1").val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because element do not exist when you are defining the event. You need to either use

1) Event Delegation

```
$("#main").on('click','#bttn',function(){
  var t = $("#txt1").val();
  alert(t);
});
```

or

2) Bind the event on success function of load event

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#bttn").click(function(){
  var t=$("#txt1").val();
  alert(t);
});
```